# swift check to see if firebase value is true or false

Tags: swift, firebase

Hello I'm retrieving some info from firebase the data I'm looking for are three child deep and consist to a boolean. When I Print the value im able to get the result but im not able to see if the result is true or false.

```
func userInfo() {

    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let stRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    dbRef.child("users/\(userBiD!)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let name = snapshot.value!["firstname"] as! String
        let profileImage = snapshot.value!["profilePic"] as! String
        let receivePostRequest = snapshot.value?["receivePostRequest"]

        self.nameLabel.text = name
        self.dbUserProfilePic(self.profilePhotoImageView, imageLink: profileImage)

        let receivePost = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("receivePostRequest")

        let tags = receivePost.childSnapshotForPath("tags")

        for child in tags.children {

            /* 
            ...
            tags{
                tag1 = true
                tag2 = false

             }
            //I need to print all keys that have a true value

            */

        }

    })

}
```

firebase json
[image]

Comment: What's the structure of `tags.children`?

Comment: @AMomchilov please take a look at the edit i added the exact json. i usually make a query where key values = true but because im inside the closure firebase will not  allow me to make a query.

Answer (score 0):

Since, according to the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDataSnapshot(py)children),
`.children` is . . .

> An iterator for *snapshots* of the child nodes in this snapshot. You can use the native `for..in` syntax.

. . . then you must use `.value` to access their data and `.key` to access their keys.

Therefore, you could do something like this.

```
func userInfo() {

    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let stRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    dbRef.child("users/\(userBiD!)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let name = snapshot.value!["firstname"] as! String
        let profileImage = snapshot.value!["profilePic"] as! String
        let receivePostRequest = snapshot.value?["receivePostRequest"]

        self.nameLabel.text = name
        self.dbUserProfilePic(self.profilePhotoImageView, imageLink: profileImage)

        let receivePost = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("receivePostRequest")

        let tags = receivePost.childSnapshotForPath("tags")

        for child in tags.children {
            // NEW
            if child.value == true {
                print(child.key)
            }
            // NEW
        }

    })

}
```

Or, if you wanted to save all true values in an array.

```
func userInfo() {

    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let stRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    dbRef.child("users/\(userBiD!)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let name = snapshot.value!["firstname"] as! String
        let profileImage = snapshot.value!["profilePic"] as! String
        let receivePostRequest = snapshot.value?["receivePostRequest"]

        self.nameLabel.text = name
        self.dbUserProfilePic(self.profilePhotoImageView, imageLink: profileImage)

        let receivePost = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("receivePostRequest")

        let tags = receivePost.childSnapshotForPath("tags")

        for child in tags.children {
            // NEW
            var trueValues: [Bool] = []

            if child.value == true {
                trueValues.append(child.key)
            }
            // NEW
        }

    })

}
```